# How to upload file on Synology NAS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, upload, nas, synology

I want to make a file and upload that on a Synology NAS. I am using Python. It doesn't support FTP but it is just a network drive.

Comment: If it is just a network drive you can use [`shutil.copyfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of network drives is that they are used like local drives. So make it accessible to your operating system (mount on Unix/Linux/MacOS, share on Windows...) and copy the file to it. Alternatively, you can use a network protocol, such as webdav, sftp, whatever is enabled. python supports them all (sometimes with some support from the OS)